# values evaluation in handlebar's {{#if}} block

Tags: ember.js

I have ArrayProxy filled with different values, and after tossing it in iterator and comparing `this` in iterator's context it always evaluated as true value, except empty array. What I'm doing wrong?

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tensai_cirno/tQPsz/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at the source, an array of length 0 evaluates to false:  https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-handlebars/lib/helpers/binding.js#L134-135

Comment: Interesting. After rigging `func` closure with `console.log`, looks like that variable `result` evaluates to class, instead of passed variable itself. Or it is because i'm passing `this` to comparator instead of value itself, but I don't think there is any other way to pass value from array.

Comment: Anyway, I'm using ember objects, instead of raw values. It works that way, and logic is more straight.